# Android NavigationView menu toggle button

Tags: java, android

I want to use toggle button or at least checkbox in my `NavigationView` for the feature of control notifications from from it(on/off).

The layout done with help of "menu.xml" file.

I tried to add `checkable="true"` but it shows nothing.
How to Implement it?

```
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_grey600_48dp"
            android:title="@string/profile" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/tutorial"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_help_grey600_48dp"
            android:title="@string/tutorial" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/checkable_menu"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:title="@string/haircut_notifications" />

    </group>

    <group
        android:id="@+id/menu_bottom"
        android:checkableBehavior="none">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_variant_grey600_48dp"
            android:title="@string/share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/selfie_videos"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_camera_front_variant_grey600_48dp"
            android:title="@string/selfie_videos" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

EDIT:

Little example at Google M with toggle just like I want to achieve.

Have any idea to do that?

[image]

Comment: NavigationView is for navigation within and app, so I wouldn't expect to use it for toggling anything.  However, it's common to use action bar menu items to be checkable toggles, which might make more sense.

Comment: @DougStevenson I just updated the question.
Could you please check image one more time so I can be sure that is not a good way to do.

Comment: If you're happy with this implementation, then by all means go with it. It seems unconventional, but maybe that doesn't matter?

Comment: @DougStevenson but how to add that programmatically?

Comment: That's a different question than what you originally asked.  Would you mind editing your question to reflect the final answer you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using app:actionLayout="@layout/item", item.xml is where you put your toggle button.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">   

 <item android:title="@string/settings_info">
        <menu>

    <item android:id="@+id/nav_number"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_room"
          android:title="@string/number"
          app:actionLayout="@layout/item"/>

    </item>

</menu>


/*How to handle the click event*/
@Override public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 

// Handle navigation view item clicks. 
    switch (item.getItemId()){ 
        case R.id.nav_network: 
            startActivity(new Intent(this, NetworkActivity.class)); break; 
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); 
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START); 
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats great!

Comment: And maybe you know how to handle then onclick exactly on this app:actionLayout item?

Comment: You should override the method onNavigationItemSelected, give a look to this example:

  @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks.

        switch (item.getItemId()){
      

            case  R.id.nav_network:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, NetworkActivity.class));
                break;

      

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

Answer (score 2):

instead of menu use recycler view so that you have lot more control over the items. The below code is tested and working.

This is the out put: 
[image: ScreenShot]

step one: create item layouts:

item_normal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="Title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

nothing fancy just image and a text

step 2: for our toggle layout lets create item_toggle.xml

item_toggle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textCustom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Notifications" />

<ToggleButton
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="New ToggleButton" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

step 3: lets create adapter for our recycler view which is going to be inside our navigation view

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

String Tag = CustomAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private final int NORMAL_VIEW = 88; // code for normal view type
private final int CUSTOM_VIEW = 99; //code for loader type

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Model> listingData = new ArrayList<>();

public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

    if (viewType == NORMAL_VIEW) {

        View normalView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_normal, parent, false);
        return new NormalItem(normalView);

    } else if (viewType == CUSTOM_VIEW) {

        View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_toogle, parent, false);
        return new CustomItem(customView);
    } else return null; // unknown type.
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (holder instanceof NormalItem) {
        // normal list item.
        ((NormalItem) holder).textView.setText(listingData.get(position).getName());
        ((NormalItem) holder).icon.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    } else if (holder instanceof CustomItem)
    {
        ((CustomItem) holder).textViewToggle.setText("On");
        ((CustomItem) holder).textViewToggle.setText("Notifications");
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listingData.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (position == 3) return CUSTOM_VIEW;
    else return NORMAL_VIEW;
}

public class NormalItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView icon;
    TextView textView;

    public NormalItem(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);

    }
}

public class CustomItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ToggleButton toggleButton;
    TextView textViewToggle;

    public CustomItem(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        toggleButton = (ToggleButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        textViewToggle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textCustom);

    }
}


/**
 * method to update the adapter and notify the adapter item by item
 *
 * @param data data to be updated.
 */
public void updateAdapter(ArrayList<Model> data) {

    try {
        for (Model item : data) {
            listingData.add(item);
            notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - 1);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(Tag, e.toString() + "");
    }

}
}
```

Step 4: create an activity_main.xml

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".main.MainActivity">


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />


    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

step 5: lets create a simple class to hold our data

Model.java

```
  public class Model {

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getItem() {
    return item;
}

public void setItem(int item) {
    this.item = item;
}

String name;
int item;
 }
```

Step 6:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
app:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:elevation="4dp"
app:layout_width="match_parent"
app:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
/>
```

final step: create MainActiivty.class

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArrayList<Model> data;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Custom Nav ");
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle mToogle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToogle);
    mToogle.syncState();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

     data = new ArrayList<>();

    Model item1 = new Model();
    item1.setName("Option 1");
    item1.setItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    Model item2 = new Model();
    item2.setName("Option 2");
    item2.setItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    Model item3 = new Model();
    item3.setItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    item3.setName("Option 3");

    Model item4 = new Model();
    item4.setItem(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    item4.setName("Option 4");


    data.add(item1);
    data.add(item2);
    data.add(item3);
    data.add(item4);
    adapter.updateAdapter(data);
}

}
```

you can add header and polish the UI according to your needs. Hope it helps.
Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks! You would achieve this view with this code and @Arturo Mejia answer is just for the question, with only one menu_item

Comment: yeah i saw it, its better, less code. if you want more control like more styling you could use this.